# Selecting a child element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three boxes with an image in each which I am trying to display when hovering over the parent element. But I only want the image for the parent which is being hovered over to appear. Here's my code;

```js
jQuery(".job_col").hover(function() {
  var current = jQuery(this);
  jQuery(current > ".plus").addClass("hi");
}, function() {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed_jobs_fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="fixed_jobs_cont">
      <div class="job_col">
        <h2 class="f_job_title">Construction Site <br class="fixed_br">Supervisor role</h2>
        <p class="f_salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
        <img class="plus" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/plus.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="job_col" id="border">
        <h2 class="f_job_title">Construction Contracts <br class="fixed_br">Manager role</h2>
        <p class="f_salary">Salary: £40,000 – £45,000</p>
        <img class="plus" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/plus.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="job_col">
        <h2 class="f_job_title">Graduate Quantity <br class="fixed_br">Surveyor role</h2>
        <p class="f_salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
        <img class="plus" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/plus.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this)` is a jQuery object, and not a string you can include inside a new selector.

Comment: use .closest() method

Comment: why do you need JQuery for this?

Comment: @Maharkus I didn't think of using css for this but now I realise if I give each an id i can just use hover thanks

Comment: @Reece feel free to check my answer, if you need help. Also don't give each element an id. You don't need to do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative solution:

You don't need jQuery to make elements appear when the parent is hovered. You can just use CSS for this!

```css
img {
display: none; }

.job_col:hover img {
display: block;
}

.job_col {
float:left;
width: 33% 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div id="fixed_jobs_cont">
                <div class="job_col">
                    <h2 class="f_job_title">Construction Site <br class="fixed_br">Supervisor role</h2>
                    <p class="f_salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
                    <img class="plus" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="job_col" id="border">
                    <h2 class="f_job_title">Construction Contracts <br class="fixed_br">Manager role</h2>
                    <p class="f_salary">Salary: £40,000 – £45,000</p>
                    <img class="plus" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="job_col">
                    <h2 class="f_job_title">Graduate Quantity <br class="fixed_br">Surveyor role</h2>
                    <p class="f_salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
                    <img class="plus" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)-function:

```
jQuery(".job_col").hover(function(){
    var current = jQuery(this);
    current.children(".plus").addClass("hi");
    }, function(){
});
```

This selects the children of the hovered `.job_col`, that has the class `plus`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(".job_col").hover(function(){
    var current = jQuery(this);
    current.find(".plus").addClass("hi");
    }, function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [find()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_find.asp) or [children()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_children.asp), both are valid in this case:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".job_col").hover(function(){
      $(this).find(".plus").addClass("hi");
      }, function(){
      $(this).find(".plus").removeClass("hi");
  });
});
```

```css
.plus{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.hi{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed_jobs_fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="fixed_jobs_cont">
                <div class="job_col">
                    <h2 class="f_job_title">Construction Site <br class="fixed_br">Supervisor role</h2>
                    <p class="f_salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
                    <img class="plus" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="job_col" id="border">
                    <h2 class="f_job_title">Construction Contracts <br class="fixed_br">Manager role</h2>
                    <p class="f_salary">Salary: £40,000 – £45,000</p>
                   <img class="plus" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="job_col">
                    <h2 class="f_job_title">Graduate Quantity <br class="fixed_br">Surveyor role</h2>
                    <p class="f_salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
                    <img class="plus" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `find()` function

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".job_col").hover(function(){
      var current = jQuery(this);
      current.find(".plus").addClass("hi");
      }, function(){
      var current = jQuery(this);
      current.find(".plus").removeClass("hi");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed_jobs_fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="fixed_jobs_cont">
                <div class="job_col">
                    <h2 class="f_job_title">Construction Site <br class="fixed_br">Supervisor role</h2>
                    <p class="f_salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
                    <img class="plus" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/plus.png" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="job_col" id="border">
                    <h2 class="f_job_title">Construction Contracts <br class="fixed_br">Manager role</h2>
                    <p class="f_salary">Salary: £40,000 – £45,000</p>
                    <img class="plus" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/plus.png" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="job_col">
                    <h2 class="f_job_title">Graduate Quantity <br class="fixed_br">Surveyor role</h2>
                    <p class="f_salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
                    <img class="plus" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/plus.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(".job_col").hover(function() {

  var current = jQuery(this);
  current.find(".plus").addClass("hi");
}, function() {

});
```

```css
.hi {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed_jobs_fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="fixed_jobs_cont">
      <div class="job_col">
        <h2 class="f_job_title">Construction Site <br class="fixed_br">Supervisor role</h2>
        <p class="f_salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
        <img class="plus" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/plus.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="job_col" id="border">
        <h2 class="f_job_title">Construction Contracts <br class="fixed_br">Manager role</h2>
        <p class="f_salary">Salary: £40,000 – £45,000</p>
        <img class="plus" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/plus.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="job_col">
        <h2 class="f_job_title">Graduate Quantity <br class="fixed_br">Surveyor role</h2>
        <p class="f_salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
        <img class="plus" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/plus.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the following code, might be helpful to you

```js
var x=0;
$('a').click(function() {
if(x==0){
$(this).parent().find('img').css('visibility','hidden');
x=1;
}
else{$(this).parent().find('img').css('visibility','visible');
x=0;
}
});
```

```css
.plus{
visibility:hidden;
}

a:hover{cursor:pointer;
user-select: none;
}div{float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="job_col">
                     <a >clik here 1</a>         
                    <img class="plus" src="http://iconbug.com/data/f6/128/942491bc40fa4b67a950d03d3d2f6399.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="job_col" id="border">
                     <a>clik here 2</a>                  
                    <img class="plus" src="http://clipart.info/images/minicovers/1496184671Wads-of-Dollars-Transparent-PNG-Clip-Art-Image.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="job_col">
                   <a>clik here 3</a>
                    <img class="plus" src="http://clipart.info/images/minicovers/1496184667100-Euro-PNG-Clipart.png" alt="">
                </div>
```